# How to get Bitmain U3 running on Linux?

Tags: linux, antminer, u3

How do I get the Bitmain U3 running on Linux?

I'm using Ubuntu Server 11.

I have downloaded the bitmain branch of cgminer and compiled it to using `CFLAGS="-O2 -Wall -march=native" ./configure --enable-bmsc`

I have also downlaoded the official 4.9.0 and used CFLAGS="-O2 -Wall -march=native" ./configure --enable-icarus` as described in the text for U3

I do a `lsusb` and it shows this:

[image: lsusb output]

cgminer just does this

[image]

Is there anything that I missed? I read that its supposed to pick up the U3 automatically with default settings, then I can over clock it a bit to get the 63ghs stable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original USB cable supplied was faulty?? After I plugged it into another USB port just above it started to kick in but went ZOMBIE after a few seconds with USB Communication error??

I took another USB cable from my old 10xErupter Mega hub. Plugged it direct into the motherboard USB slot and U3 (also shorter cable).  `cgminer` started to do all kinds of weird settings until it settled down on `AU3`.

Using the official git, I compiled `cgminer` (This also works for Raspberry Pi)

```
CFLAGS="-O2 -Wall -march=native" ./configure --enable-icarus
```

*NOTE: Since version 4.9.0 you should not need to use any au3 switches*

After that I set cgminer to `--au3-freq 238 --au3-volt 780` Allot of people say that when you go higher than 780 with the stock 6A power supply it melts in about 10 hours.

So when I get round to using my computer PSU I will clock these at 250/800 as recomended for best speed stability.

[image]

Comment: Everything described here was successful for my instalation Antminer U3 on Ubuntu 14.04. Thanks a lot!